# Using twisted to selectively reverse proxy to different servers

Tags: python, python-3.x, twisted, reverse-proxy

I'm using Twisted (well `twistd` actually) to serve content like this currently :

```
twistd -n -o web --path=./foo/
```

That's fine but I want to send some requests to another server - like this.

When the client requests

```
localhost/something.html
```

I want the request to be handled by the `twistd` server .

But when the client requests

```
localhost/api/somedata
```

I want the request to be reverse proxied to another server .

So in summary if the URL contains the string "api" then I want the request reverse proxied elsewhere.

I can see that Twisted has a [built in Reverse Proxy](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.proxy.ReverseProxyResource.html) but I don't know how to use that so that I can filter requests made in such a way that some requests would get sent off to the alternative server and some wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

`ReverseProxyResource` is a resource.  You can place it into a resource hierarchy.

```
root = Resource()
root.putChild("something.html", SomethingHTML())
root.putChild("api", ReverseProxyResource(...))
```

This is just one example of an arrangement of the resource hierarchy.  You can combine `ReverseProxyResource` with other resources in any of the ways supported by `IResource`.